# prolog and translating propositional logic

Tags: prolog, logic, boolean-logic

My ultimate goal is to load a set of propositional formulas in to Prolog from a file in order to deduce some facts. Suppose I have the propositional formula:

```
p implies not(q).
```

In Prolog this would be:

```
not(q) :- p
```

Prolog does not seem to like the `not` operator in the head of the rule. I get the following error:

```
 '$record_clause'/2: No permission to redefine built-in predicate `not/1'
        Use :- redefine_system_predicate(+Head) if redefinition is intended
```

I know two ways to rewrite the general formula for `p implies q`. First, use the fact that the contrapositive is logically equivalent.

`p implies q` iff `not(q) implies not(p)`

Second, use the fact that `p implies q` is logically equivalent to `not(p) or q` (the truth tables are the same).

The first method leads me to my current problem. The second method is then just a conjunction or disjunction. You cannot write only conjunctions and disjunctions in Prolog as they are not facts or rules.

1. What is the best way around my problem so that I can express `p implies not(q)`?
2. Is it possible to write all propositional formulas in Prolog?

**EDIT:** Now I wish to connect my results with other propositional formulae. Suppose I have the following rule:

`something :- formula(P, Q).`

How does this connect? If I enter `formula(false, true)` (which evaluates to true) into the interpreter, this does not automatically make `something` true. Which is what I want.

Comment: All you have to do is choose a different name. `not/1` is a built-in in your Prolog implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p => ~q  ===  ~p \/ ~q  === ~( p /\ q )
```

So we can try to model this with a Prolog program,

```
formula(P,Q) :- P, Q, !, fail.
formula(_,_).
```

Or you can use the built-in `\+` i.e. "not", to define it as `formula(P,Q) :- \+( (P, Q) ).`

This just checks the compliance of the passed values to the formula. If we combine this with domain generation first, we can "deduce" i.e. generate the compliant values:

```prolog
13 ?- member(Q,[true, false]), formula(true, Q).  %// true => ~Q, what is Q?
Q = false.

14 ?- member(Q,[true, false]), formula(false, Q). %// false => ~Q, what is Q?
Q = true ;
Q = false.
```

Comment: I have little to no experience with prolog. What is the point of using `member`? I just wrote out the formula and passed true and false.

Comment: Additionally, how would I connect the logic to my other logical deductions? Suppose something else is true if formula is true. We would have the rule: `something :- formula(P, Q)`. I'll make this more clear in an edit.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus the point of `member` is to generate the possible values for a variable. The logical variables are what becomes true or false. `true` or `false` are not Boolean values in Prolog; the are special goals; `true` always succeeds and `false` (and its synonym, `fail`) always fail. You should study some tutorial to acquaint yourself with Prolog. :)

Answer (score -2):

You are using the wrong tool. Try Answer Set Programming.